# Can't find eth0 in my ifconfig output

Tags: keyboard, kali-linux, ethernet, bios

I have a old desktop with ASUS P5KPL AM/PS board with intel core2Duo processor. I have installed kali linux on it when I run ifconfig in root shell all I can see `l0`which is my loopback address and nothing else can be found. It seems that it will require to install the motherboard drivers but I can not find drivers for the boards on linux. Is it really the drivers issue or something else? and another issue is the keyboard is not detected during the initial POST until the one of the multiple installed OS is booted. What should be done in order to detect the keyboard. I cannot even go to BIOS setup as the keyboard itself is not detected at the OEM logo.

Answer (score 1):

1. The bios can be entered by using the Del key on the keyboard. The folowing quote is from the official user manual which can be foud [here](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P5KPLAM/HelpDesk_Manual/):

> The firmware chip on the motherboard stores the Setup utility. When you start up the
>   computer, the system provides you with the opportunity to run this program. Press "Del"
>   during the Power-On Self-Test (POST) to enter the Setup utility. Otherwise, POST continues
>   with its test routines.

2. The drivers for your network card can be found on the realtek site [here](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=14&PFid=7&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false). I don't know kali linux but for some distributions you can download and install kmod packages with realtek (and some other hardware).